# Deleted all .list files on /etc/apt/sources.list.d* recover elementary .list files

Tags: release-loki, sources

Hello I'm a linux noob and I've done a mess with the sources.list.d folder trying to resolve an issue with repos. I've executed these lines of code:

```
sudo rm -r /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

but I've deleted all the .list files. Where there any elementary specific repo? I'm using loki 0.4

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, i'm noob too, but I have a elementary.list file there and it contains:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu xenial main

deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu xenial main
```

I'm using loki too

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! is there anything else that I should add? Like others system related ppas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is another file named `patches.list` and that's it.

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu xenial main

deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu xenial main
```